# Prove or disprove that $f(x)=ax^{(2b+1)}$ is injective by using the contrapositive.

Tags: proof-writing, notation, proof-explanation

I'm just getting into proofs, so a clear and intuitive explanation here would be most appreciated. I'm not sure if this is the correct notation either. How would I go about proving $$(\forall x, a \in \mathbb R)(\forall b \in \mathbb N)\{f(x)=ax^{2b+1}: x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)\}, a \neq0$$ I am essentially concerned with figuring out if there are any odd-powered functions that are not injective. Thank you!

Comment: Your alternative isn't correct.  Injective and surjective are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Should $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\neq 0$? If $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then we can let $b=-1/2$ for which your statement is false.

Comment: @BernardPan Note OP has added your two conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f(x_2)-f(x_1)=a(x_2^{2b+1}-x_1^{2b+1})=a(x_2-x_1)(x_2^{2b}+x_2^{2b-1}x_1+\cdots+x_2x_1^{2b-1}+x_1^{2b}).$$
First, by assumption, we know that $x_2-x_1\neq 0$. Denote $$S:=x_2^{2b}+x_2^{2b-1}x_1+\cdots+x_2x_1^{2b-1}+x_1^{2b}.$$

Without loss of generality, we assume $x_1<x_2$.

1. If $x_1=0$, then $S=x_2^{2b}>0$. Similarly, if $x_2=0$, then $S=x_1^{2b}>0$.
2. If $x_1>0$, then $x_2>0$ and clearly $S>0$.
3. If $x_2<0$, then $x_1<0$. Suppose $x_1=-x_1'$ and $x_2=-x_2'$ where $x_1',x_2'>0$. Then $$x_2^ix_1^{2b-i}=(-x_2')^{i}(-x_1')^{2b-i}=(-1)^{2b}\cdot(x_2')^i(x_1')^{2b-i}=(x_2')^i(x_1')^{2b-i}>0.$$ Hence $S>0$ as well.

In the first three cases, we have $f(x_2)-f(x_1)\neq 0$, so $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. As for the last case,

4. Finally, assume $x_1<0<x_2$. Observe that $$f(x_1)f(x_2)=a^2(\underbrace{x_1x_2}_{<0})^{2b+1}<0,$$ so $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. If they are equal, then we must have $f(x_1)f(x_2)\geq 0$.